# Windows Does Not Boot after Changing Non-Active Partition to Logic

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I had three partitions C, D, and E on my MBR disk, visible in Explorer in Windows 7. I had already run out of primary partitions and had problem installing Linux. So, I used MiniTool Partition Wizard and changed type of two partitions D and E to logical. Then, Windows explorer showed only C and D and E became hidden. I restarted the system and it will not boot up.
Is there any bootable live CD solution I can use to save the system and boot up Windows again?

[image]

Update:
The error message says

> loadstd
>
> Failed to load system data.
>
> InitProtectSystem failed.

I just realized this is because Rollback Rx has been installed on the computer. This has to do something with it.  I did not know about Rollback Rx before messing with the partitions.

Comment: You can try a [gparted](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) live CD/USB stick to fix your partition table. You could also boot from a Windows DVD and repair it from there as explained on [this page](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/)

Comment: Is Windows on your PC using 2 partitions? A boot partition and a second one containing the rest of the OS as in the screenshot on the top of [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/192772/what-is-the-system-reserved-partition-and-can-you-delete-it/) page? Are you sure you didn't change C to logical partition by accident?

Comment: @SpiderPig It had four partitions but only showed three in Explorer. After the MiniTool operation I only saw C: in Explorer. yes I'm pretty sure I only changed non-Windows partitions.

Comment: Can you uninstall Rollback Rx without having to boot into Windows? Once it's gone the Windows setup DVD should be able to fix any boot problems you have.